# Weird C++ template & const problem

Tags: c++, templates

I don't understand why the output of this program is **Second method** instead of **First Method**...

```
#include <iostream>

template <class T>
void assign(T& t1,T& t2){
    std::cout << "First method"<< std::endl;
}

template <class T>
void assign(T& t1,const T& t2) {
    std::cout << "Second method"<< std::endl;
}

class A
{
public:
    A(int a):_a(a){};
private:
    int _a;
    friend A operator+(const A& l, const A& r);
};

A operator+(const A& l, const A& r) {
friend A operator+(const A& l, const A& r);return A(l._a+r._a);
}

int main ()
{
    A a=1;
    const A b=2;
    assign(a,a+b);
}
```

However, when I change my main function to this:

```
int main ()
{
    A a=1;
    const A b=2;
    A c=a+b;
    assign(a,c);
}
```

The output is **First method**.
Any ideas?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

```
assign( a, a+b );
```

The result of `a + b` is an *rvalue expression* of type `A` that creates a temporary and you cannot bind it to a non-const reference, so it picks up the `const` overload as you are allowed to bind a const reference to a temporary.

```
assign( a, c );
```

In this case, the subexpression `c` is an *lvalue expression* and you are allowed to bind a non-const reference. In this case, because the non-const version is a perfect match with `T=A` it is preferred over the const overload that would require a conversion in the second argument from an *lvalue of type `A`* to *const lvalue of type `A`*.

Comment: @Nawaz: I am not too sure of that edit, but I'll leave it as it is. In the standard references *bind* to expressions not the other way around. Then again English is not my native language, and this expression is more convoluted so I would not know :)

Comment: Searching the standard for uses of 'bound', 'bind' and 'binding', you can find uses that go both ways although binding a reference to an entity is a little more common. I think that it is supposed to be a symmetric action.

Answer (score 5):

`&t2` in your functions is taking a reference.

However, `a+b` cannot be bound to a normal reference, so it has to be passed as a `const` reference.

In your second `main` you're passing in a proper lvalue, so it can be modified by the function (and hence the `const` may change the meaning).

<strike>That's my guess, at least.</strike>

Comment: Please don't answer if it's a guess.

Comment: Even if it is right? From the wording of it, it does seem as if *mange* does know what he/she is saying...

Comment: He definitely knows it's something like this and he knows that it's quite likely that he's right. But, as he said, it is a guess.

Comment: OK, next time I just won't say it's a guess. I know I'm right, I'm just not sure of the precise terminology.

Comment: @David: Indeed, that's how things like `vector<foo>().swap(vec)` works for shrinking a vector's allocation (and the seemingly-similar `vec.swap(vector<foo>())` will not compile). (BTW, I am sorry for not clarifying this in my answer. I would have cleared it up, but like I mentioned, your answer is in any case better, so I don't need to keep mine around.)

Comment: @mange: You should fix the issue pointed out by David. I will undo my downvote.